# Gym wrapper videorecorder is not working properly on Hopper-v2 environment. Gives segmentation fault

Tags: python-3.x, linux, segmentation-fault, ubuntu-20.04, openai-gym

I am trying to save a video of the render of my Hopper-v2 environment, however it gives a segmentation fault error. I have made a short code example to reproduce the issue.

```
import os
from gym.wrappers.monitoring.video_recorder import VideoRecorder

path_project = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, ".."))
path_of_video_with_name = os.path.join(path_project, "videotest.mp4")
env = gym.make('Hopper-v2') # for making environment
state = env.reset()
video_recorder = None
video_recorder = VideoRecorder(env, path_of_video_with_name, enabled=True)

for _ in range(1000):
   env.render()
   video_recorder.capture_frame()
   env.step(env.action_space.sample()) # take a random action

print("Saved video.")

video_recorder.close()
video_recorder.enabled = False
env.close()
```

This gives the error:
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

It does create a video though, which is only 14 frames long, then it gets interrupted. By commenting out the 'video_recorder.capture_frame()' line, it will render the complete episode. Using the cartpole environment instead of the hopper, does work and saves the complete episode.

I am using Linux 20.0.4 (Ubuntu), Gym version 0.21.0 using `pip install gym`, python version 3.7.6.

If anyone has any idea, please let me know

Comment: okay, using ```env = gym.wrappers.Monitor(env, path_of_video_with_name)``` does work. still strange that the other solution gives an error

Answer (score 0):

Install the following dependencies;

```
pip install ffmpeg
pip install imageio-ffmpeg
```

Resolved my issue.